# Conditionally join with previous list entry using comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to fix some broken linux paths in a list I am working with.

List:

```
mylist = ['/root/path/path', '/cat', '/dog', '/root/path/path', '/blue', '/red']
```

Requirements:

If element does not begin with `'/root'`, join to the element to the left of it.

Code so far:

```
mylist2 = [''.join(x) for x in mylist]

print(mylist2)
```

Expected output:

```
['/root/path/path/cat/dog', '/root/path/path/blue/red']
```

Actual output:

```
['/root/path/path', '/cat', '/dog', '/root/path/path', '/blue', '/red']
```

I've also tried:

```
mylist2 = [''.join(x) if myroot not x for mylist]
```

...which produces a syntax error...

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "what I am doing wrong": in that list comprehension, x is 1 path/string inside the list at a time. when you try to use `''.join(x)` you are essentially just treating the string as an iterable, and joining it with nothing in between, thus essentially getting back your original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one method using list comprehension:

```
mylist2 = ['/root' + x for x in ''.join(mylist).split('/root') if x]  # if x eliminates the empty split elements

# ['/root/path/path/cat/dog', '/root/path/path/blue/red']
```

Since your goal is basically to join everything and then split them by `/root`, this line of list comprehension does exactly that and adds `/root` back to each element.

But as you can see, given just the code, @chepner's answer is much more understandable and clearer.  Just because list comprehension exist doesn't mean it should be your go-to.

Also I should note, if there's `/root` within any of your elements (not necessarily at the beginning), this code will also separate it because of the split, so it's not as exact as explicitly going through the loop.  If you wanted to handle that scenario it becomes very ugly...:

```
['/root' + y for y in ''.join("_" + x if x.startswith("/root") else x for x in lst).split("_/root") if y]

# eww
```

Answer (score 6):

This is simpler if you just use a regular loop. The problem with the list comprehension is that you don't have a uniform operation on each element of the first list that creates an element for the new list. (Think of a list comphension as a combination of `map` and `filter`. You can map one old value to one new value, or drop an old value, but you can't combine multiple old values into a single new value.)

```
mylist2 = []
for path in mylist:
    if path.startswith('/root'):
        mylist2.append(path)
    else:
        mylist2[-1] += path
```

(This is only partially correct; it assumes the first element of `mylist` will actually start with `/root`, so that `mylist2[-1]` will never be used if `mylist2` is empty.)